# Jose4j: HttpsJwks thread safe?

Tags: jwt, jose4j

Anyone know if HttpsJwks usage is thread safe?
We got about 60 - 100 calls per second in an application where we are going to use HttpsJwks, but I don't see any locking when it comes to refreshing Jwks.

Also, HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver directly call's refresh if it fails to find a key.

Kind regards, Kenneth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be, yes. There's no locking but the only shared data is the cache object and it is set with a single assignment. It's used often in multithreaded situations.

Comment: Yes, I checked the source as well. But lets say I get 50 requests/sec.
The call to JWKS endpoint takes 100 ms to respond, it won't lock at all, and many calls will be made to JWKS endpoint since there is no lock (can do a 2 step verification sync lock or something).


I will test it out using Gatling, but the moment the cache expires, there might be many calls overriding the cache.

Comment: an improved concurrency approach will be in the next version with https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/commits/b577cb539b09cb691e848244dea1769c3f7921b9 and https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/commits/987966ba3b56c5238f1e2b83f812d73339811c52 based on https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/pull-requests/13/make-httpsjwks-threadsafe/diff

Comment: improved concurrency approach is out in v 0.6.4 https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Release%20Notes